# Visa fees for an Indian visa

Tags: visas, fees-and-charges

I am looking to travel to India to explore their culture and their heritage next month. What are the fees when applying for a tourist visa for an Australian? I checked many websites but everyone has mentioned only service fees not the total fees.

Below are the websites I checked:

- https://indiaevisas.org/
- https://www.indianvisaonline.org.in/

Comment: `The visa fee depends upon the type of applied for and duration of visa. Visa fee is divided into various types depending upon the case viz; Basic fee, special fee, processing fee by out-sourcing agency. During the online registration process, at the end of the process the basic fee shall be displayed. However, this fee shall be indicative only and final fee shall be charged while submitting the application at the respective counters`

Comment: The official eVisa site is here: https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html#

Answer (score 1):

There are several 'services' you could use to help you get a visa.

However, as a potentially complicated candidate (born in South Africa, NZ citizen, living in Australia, can't get an  ESTA after visiting Iran), applying via [the official Indian government visa website](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html#) was still a reasonably straightforward process.

Unless you have an exceptional circumstance, or other complication, I'd recommend just applying via the government website.

The official site also states:

> Services of e-Visa involves completely online application for which no
>   facilitation is required by any intermediary / agents etc. It is
>   advised not to believe or fall in trap of any such unscrupulous
>   elements who claim speedy/express grant of e-Visa and charge money for
>   it.

The visa fee can change, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_India) (Policy of India), the latest cost as of June would be around US$80.